# converting multiple list in dictionary and build dataframe to write a csv file

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to read multiple files, converting to a dictionary and then save it into a csv.
This is what I did, but I only keeps the last iteration of the files.
'''
list_keys = ["hostname", "linuxVersion", "ifconfig",
"listApplications", "nonJavaProcess", "javaProcess", "tomcatIfRunning",          "tomcatVersion"]
files = glob.glob('data/*', recursive=True)

```
new_data = []
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json_file.read()
        split_json = data.split('][')
        new_data.append(split_json)

dictionary = {}
final_dictionary = {}

for list in new_data:
    dictionary = dict(zip(list_keys, list))
        final_dictionary.update(dictionary)


dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(final_dictionary, index=[0], columns=list_keys)
dataframe.to_csv("relevamiento.csv", index=False)
```

'''
The formating is OK in the CSV, but I only have the last file I read.

any ideas?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the dict in a dataframe to the large dataframe

```
new_data = []
dictionary = {}
final_dictionary = {}
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json_file.read()
        split_json = data.split('][')
        new_data.append(split_json)

    for list in new_data:
        dictionary = dict(zip(list_keys, list))
        final_dictionary.update(dictionary)
        df1 = pandas.DataFrame(final_dictionary, index=[0], columns=list_keys)
        dataframe = dataframe.append(df1)
    dictionary = {} ###
    final_dictionary = {} ###
    new_data = [] ####
dataframe.to_csv("relevamiento.csv", index=False)
```

if json isn't required, you can do it in a lot less code

```
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file)
    dataframe = dataframe.append(df1)

dataframe.to_csv("relevamiento.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan! the first version works for me. the second I've already tried and threw me an exception. Now, the first option, duplicates the first "file" in two rows, while the second one is OK. what do you thinks is going on here?

Comment: @PabloM try adding the two lines I added to the first code block

Comment: I try that but I still have the same situation, in fact if I put more files to read every row gets duplicated. :(

Comment: Reset the list like i just modified above. I missed that on my first edit.

Comment: Stefan.. i tried to add what you put above but the dataframe gets empty now... i also tried to put the second for outside the for file in files but i get an index error in  the pandas.Dataframe line.

Answer (score 0):

@stefan_aus_hannover I could solve the duplicate issue adding the following prior to save to csv file:

'''

```
final_dataframe = dataframe.drop_duplicates(subset="hostname")
final_dataframe.to_csv("relevamiento.csv", index=False)
```

'''
Thank you very much for your help!!